# web api method not receiving parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core API that when submitting through postman parameter values the values are not received.  What am I doing wrong?

**Postman Example**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
[HttpGet("/{clientId}/{emailType}", Name = "GetEmailConfigurations")]
public async Task<EmailConfigurationsModel> GetEmailConfigurations(Guid clientId, int emailType)
{
    return await _emailService.GetEmailConfigurations(clientId, emailType);
}
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: I did not have any http headers.  I needed to provide the Content-type : application/json http header.  This fixed my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not provided the content type in a header.  Once I added content-type = application/json all started working correctly.